# ExtJS/Larvavel inserting data into PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, extjs, laravel-4

I'm using ExtJS, Laravel and PostgreSQL. When i want to add/insert data using POST method i get:
 Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException

The same thing happens when i want to see the array of $all using print_r
How do i resolve this problem.

Partial code of ExtJS:

```
  Ext.Ajax.request({
    url : 'books/create',
    method    : 'POST',
    jsonData  : values,
    success   : function(response) {
      var resp = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);
      Ext.Msg.show({
        title : 'Confirmation',
        msg   : resp.data.msg,
        width : 400,
        buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,
        fn    : function(btn) {
          if(btn == 'ok') {
            store.load();
            win.close();
          }
        },
        icon  : Ext.MessageBox.INFO
      });
    },
    failure: function(response) {
      Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', 'Failed to create/update Book details.');
      win.close();
    }
  });
```

Laravel route:

```
Route::post('books/create', 'BookController@create');
```

And Laravel Controller

```
public function create()
{
    $input = Input::all();

    if ($inpiut['id'] == '')
    {

        Book::create($input);
        return Response::json(array('msg'=>'New Books record successfully created.'));
    }
    else
    {
        $book = Book::where('id', '=', $all['id']);
        $book -> update($all);
        return Response::json(array('msg' => 'Book successfully update.'));
    }
}
```

Comment: The `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` in laravel normally pops up when you have mismatched request actions, e.g. you try to post to a get route, but that doesn't seem to be the case here. If you create a quick html page with a form and set the form's action to `books/create` and it's method to `POST`, do you get the same exception?

Comment: Actually the problem was i used Laravel create, it automatically adds the update field that i don't have in database table. So instead i used {$books = DB::table('books')->insertGetId(array('title'} and it works fine now.